# How to add array in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays like this:

```
//Find the column
if($second_z==0.00){
  $valueColumn = $zero_list;
} else if($second_z==0.01){
  $valueColumn = $one_list;
} else if($second_z==0.02){
  $valueColumn = $two_list;
} else if($second_z==0.03){
  $valueColumn = $three_list;
} else if($second_z==0.04){
  $valueColumn = $four_list;
} else if($second_z==0.05){
  $valueColumn = $five_list;
} else if($second_z==0.06){
  $valueColumn = $six_list;
} else if($second_z==0.07){
  $valueColumn = $seven_list;
} else if($second_z==0.08){
  $valueColumn = $eight_list;
} else if($second_z==0.09){
  $valueColumn = $nine_list;
} else {}
```

and all this arrays, I want to insert into array:

```
$valueColumn_list[] = $valueColumn;

//I want the result if printing this array
$valueColumn_list = array($zero_list,$one_list,...);
```

but it said error -> **Cannot use a scalar value as an array**

so anyone has the solution for it?

Thanks.

Comment: and what is the error..?

Comment: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Comment: off topic: The sequential nature of your `$second_z` variable negates the need for those horrible `if-else` statements...

Comment: The statement `$valueColumn_list[] = $valueColumn;` is not valid, try `$valueColumn_list = $valueColumn;`

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to merge the array ?

Comment: @monojit - yes monojit, sorry for not being clear, I just found it, use array_merge. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Shot in the dark here: `$valueColumn_list = array("zero_list" => $zero_list, "one_list" => $one_list,...);`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by following way..

valueColumn_list = array();

```
if($second_z==0.00)
{
  valueColumn_list['zero_list'] = $zero_list;    //if $zero_list is array
}
else if($second_z==0.01)
{
  valueColumn_list['one_list'] = $one_list;
} 
else if($second_z==0.02)
{
   valueColumn_list['two_list']= $two_list;
}
.
.
.
```